# Identifying significantly different groups in a logistic regression model

Tags: logistic, multiple-comparisons, biostatistics, post-hoc, contingency-tables

In my experiment, I compare the resistance of 12 different seed types to seed beetles. I have 30 replications (i.e. 30 times a single beetle larva developing in a single seed) for each variety and assess whether an adult beetle emerges from the seed or not.
The resulting two-way table I analyzed using logistic regression with the factor "variety" and the binary response "development completed / not completed". The analysis revealed that the groups are significantly different. Now I'd like to do a *post-hoc* test to identify which varieties are significantly different from one another (similar to a Tukey's HSD for ANOVA). Is there a way to do this?

Thank you very much for your support!